# Why is jQuery clone making events not draggable onto calendar? fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, clone

I have added another div for external events in my FullCalendar implementation and the idea is to have this div storing favourites for later use if the user wish to (to visually illustrate the idea --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiYBV.jpg). Im successfully able to drag and drop events from the first div to the second and i'm also able to drag them from div2 but NOT onto the calendar for some reason:

```
 // 2nd div droppable setting
 $('#external-events-fav').droppable( {
        accept: '#external-events .fc-event',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var droppable = $(this); 
            var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
            clone.draggable({ // clone element then make it draggable
                helper: 'clone',
                appendTo: 'body',
                scroll: false,
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0
            }).appendTo(droppable); 
        }
    });
```

If I don't make the ui.draggable.clone() call, I'm able to drag the event from the new div to the calendar but i want to make a clone, so I can have the event appearing in both divs. Creating the clone using jQuery clone() makes it undraggable onto the calendar however for unknown reasons. Anyone know why? I have tried clone(true) and clone(true,true) but this didnt help the situation either.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a3q9c5tr/37

still need help with this :(

Comment: Makes it `undraggable` or `undroppable` onto the calendar?

Comment: `ui.draggable` is a function, then why `.clone()`?

Comment: i cant drop it onto the calendar, it will not stick if i call .clone()

Comment: highly inspired by this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711222/keep-a-copy-of-an-element-when-using-jquery-drag-and-drop" when making this code

Comment: Does the cloned object match the selector `#external-events .fc-event`? Is it inside `#external-events` and has the class `fc-event`? If not, that's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or snippet to show the problem and play around?

Comment: working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a3q9c5tr/37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. jQUery clone() function does not copy over the data attributes set by jQuery data('event', {}) function so i had to do this again for the clone in order to make it work, so therefore:

```
$('#external-events-fav').droppable( {
    accept: '#external-events .fc-event',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var droppable = $(this); 
        var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
        clone.data('event' { 
             title : ui.draggable.attr("name"),
             // INSERT MORE ATTR HERE
        });
        clone.data('duration',ui.draggable.attr('duration'));
        clone.draggable({ // clone element then make it draggable
            helper: 'clone',
            appendTo: 'body',
            scroll: false,
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0
        }).appendTo(droppable); 
    }
});
```

Hope this might help anyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments I am assuming your problem description is as follows:

> The cloned object is draggable (you can click and drag it around your
>   page) but not droppable onto the calendar (when you lift your finger
>   over the calendar the object goes back to its original position or it's simply not recorded as dropped).

If that's the case, my first guess it that the cloned object does not match the `droppable` `accept` selector. Is your cloned object inside `#external-events` and does it have the class `fc-event`?

If it does, you probably have to append it to the right place of the DOM before calling the `draggable` function on it. Try it like this:

```
$('#external-events-fav').droppable( {
    accept: '#external-events .fc-event',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
        clone.appendTo(this); 
        clone.draggable({ // clone element then make it draggable
            helper: 'clone',
            scroll: false,
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0
        });  
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem description you posted is correct and yes it goes back to the original position when i attempt to drop it onto the calendar. The copy is created when i drag the element from div1 to div2 and therefore it is inside 'external-events-fav'.  Is your cloned object inside #external-events? **No**.  Does it have the class fc-event? **Yes** console.log on console gives: div#10817.fc-event.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle

Comment: console.log on console = console.log on clone **

Comment: If your cloned object is not inside `#external-events` then it won't match the `accept` attribute and will not be droppable onto the `#external-events-fav`. What if you use `accept: '.fc-event'` instead? That should make your clone droppable as well. Either that or append the clone inside the `#external-events`.

Comment: i changed the accept attribute to '.fc-event' and im still able to drag objects from `#external-events` to `#external-events-fav` as well as dragging & dropping objects in `#external-events-fav` to `#external-events-fav` to create dublicates(which is nice but not the main concern). Problem still remains that im unable to drag and drop the clone onto the calendar.

Comment: i dont see why the calendar would accept `fc-event` from `#external-events` but not an identical clone residing in `#external-events-fav`. Makes no sense to me.